# virtual super computer with Red Hat

Tags: centos, rhel, virtual-machine, kvm

[These specifications](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-kvm-limits) indicate that the maximum size of a Red Hat 7 virtual machine includes 240 virtual CPUs and 4TB of RAM.

Clearly, these maximums seem to be describing a virtual machine that runs on many physical boxes.  I am imagining 80 quad-core physical boxes each contributing 3 cores to such a mammoth virtual machine.  These maximums seem to be describing a virtual super computer.

**Can someone please document examples of such a mammoth virtual computer?  Perhaps instructions for how to build one?**  The documentation I have found for Red Hat virtual machines all seems to give examples of small virtual machines with perhaps only two virtual CPUs per virtual machine.

Comment: I used to support systems/researchers that used remote HPC systems. I never seriously considered using HPC as a hypervisor for a VM, but a quick Google came back with lots of interesting looking results... http://ieee-hpec.org/2012/index_htm_files/HPEC12_Reuther.pdf

Comment: I really don't get the point of this question.  Even if no such machine existed today, it might tomorrow or the day after.  These are the limitations to that specific system, period.

Comment: @JuliePelletier The point of the question is to learn how to approach the design of such a massive virtual machine.  Even if, to your point, limitations are expanded later, the same design principles would apply.  It would be nice if an automation system could replace a network of virtual machines with a massive virtual super computer to perform certain tasks, and then tear down that massive virtual supercomputer to rebuild the previous network as needed.

Comment: That could be nice but it would have a huge overhead, making it a bad idea.  That said, there are applications to stacking computer processing but they do not attempt to build a massive OS.  Instead they act as job servers that receive specific task requests and send back the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much doubt that KVM supports virtual machines spread over multiple physical hosts. You can buy physical systems big enough to host such huge VMs: an eight-socket Xeon E7-8800 series system will provide up to 24 cores per socket, with two threads per core (so 384 threads in total), and support at least 6TiB of RAM, easily hosting a 240-vCPU VM with 4TiB of RAM. (And that’s just a standard Intel example; some systems support [even more cores](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/slides/lfcs09_travis.pdf).)

I don’t know of any publicly-documented examples of such VMs off-hand though.

Answer (score 0):

Not "clearly" at all. There are systems out there with a very high cpu count in a single host. No hypervisor supports a vm spread across multiple hosts.